# JPush - pushing notifications in China

Tags: android, push-notification

I need to push notifications to the android mobile application in China.
Have somebody an example of using JPush? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pushy founder here. JPush can be a little hard to understand since it's in Chinese -- check out [Pushy](https://pushy.me/) as an alternative English push notification provider in China.

Answer (score 0):

Ok，jPush，xiaomiPush,baiduPush ,getui,and so on everyont is ok.
There is some samples

[JPUSH Doc](http://docs.jpush.cn/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3309574)

you can visite this website https://www.jpush.cn/

[image: login]

In the top of right,please click "登录" and input username(登录账号/用户名):haoxiqiang
password(登录密码):111222 .

Then you can see console like this
[image: consol]

click 下载 Android Example

Now you can get it.If you need others,I think I can upload these to github.

Comment: In order to use JPushInterface do I need to download Push-API-v3 ? In your project mainActivity implements server side the pushes notifications, wright ? Where is a client side, that should run on the mobile phone and receives notifications? Is it a MyReceiver? It should be a service runs in background, shouldn't it? Thanks in advance, Julia

Comment: oh， sorry.I fotget you can't read chinese in the consol.“发送通知” means send notification to client, ofcourse you can you server to send.I had upload samples to github. [https://github.com/Haoxiqiang/china-sdk-sample](https://github.com/Haoxiqiang/china-sdk-sample)

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to build my own example using your example. And I got the following error running the client: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jpush from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.julia_n.jpushtest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.julia_n.jpushtest-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary  returned null.     I added libs/jpush-sdk-release1.5.5.jar. What more do I need? Is the server and client projects are independent? Or they have to be a part of the same solution?

Comment: Do you have this file? jdemo/libs/armeabi/libjpush.so

Comment: yes, I have libjpush163.so. When I call JPushInterface.init(this) I got the following exception : 08-11 08:39:38.563: W/dalvikvm(1087): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcn/jpush/android/service/PushProtocol; Looks like something missing...

Comment: maybe the version is different.you should use jar and so with the same version code.